# What information about my app and its host OS would it be useful to send to the server?

Tags: android, ios

It might be useful to send this information to the server in case I discover bugs in my app that manifest on certain versions. In those cases I may be able to avoid those bugs in the client by working around them in the server.

1. iOS or Android
2. OS Version number
3. App version number

It might be useful to send this information to the server so that the server doesn't overload the host OS's resources.

1. Free disk space

What information am I missing? Thank you!

Comment: This question does not belong here. You could send crashdumps however.

Comment: Use some pre-existing third party service, such as Flurry or Fabric or one of about one hundred more.  They will collect all that stuff for you and give you a nice dashboard to view it with.

Comment: @Akaino Why doesn't the question belong here?

Comment: @i_am_jorf I will use a crash analytics service, however that service would not enable me to code my server to work around bugs in different versions of my app or the OS.

Answer (score 1):

I would also add (for Android) the model name and/or model number of the device